# Varchar field from a view set to wrong length in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, crystal-reports

I'm using a view in my SqlServer database as a source of Crystal Reports document.

In my view I have some field created dynamically  (forgive me Polish language) :

```
ALTER VIEW    
SELECT
...
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(L.NumerListu_Fedex,'')<>'' THEN 'FEDEX' ELSE 'NIEOKREŚLONY' END) As Przewoznik
...
GO
```

When I use this field in Crystal Reports its length is however somehow set to 5 chars"[image]

I even tried in sql:

```
CAST((CASE WHEN ISNULL(L.NumerListu_Fedex,'')<>'' THEN 'FEDEX' ELSE 'NIEOKREŚLONY' END)AS varchar(50)) As Przewoznik
```

but it still doesn't work.

Anybody has an idea how to set this field longer? It currently trims my texts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CASTing the 'FEDEX' itself, like this:

```
ALTER VIEW    
SELECT
...
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(L.NumerListu_Fedex,'')<>'' THEN CAST('FEDEX' AS VARCHAR(50)) ELSE 'NIEOKREŚLONY' END) As Przewoznik
...
GO
```